# Lua check if variable's type is float

Tags: floating-point, lua

How to check if type of a variable is float?
Float isn't basic type of values in Lua, so function type() return only *number*.

Comment: If i remember correctly, _all_ numbers are floating point in Lua. Integers are only floating point numbers without the decimals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All numbers in Lua are floating point<sup>1</sup>. You can tell is a number *represents* a number with non-zero fractional part by using [`math.modf`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial).

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless lua's code itself is compiled with a flag that instructs it to use integers instead of floating-point numbers, in which case you cannot use floating point numbers in your programs at all.

Comment: You can also check if a number has a fractional part with `n%1 == 0`

Answer (score 4):

math.type() tells you if the number is a float or an integer. It's only available on Lua 5.3

See the Lua 5.3 Reference Manual of math functions 
https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.7

Comment: However, `print(math.type(0.5 + 0.5))` prints "float" -- it's giving you the storage type which may not be what you want.